# Why is my object shaped differently in object mode than in edit mode?

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

Why is my object shaped differently in object mode than in edit mode?

[image]

Here's the model in object mode. (The undesired shape)

[image]

Here's the model in edit mode. (The desired shape)

Comment: Hello :). Differences between *Object/Edit mode* are usually caused by modifiers. See if you have one that's only enabled for object mode.

Comment: That's an answer more than a comment. Consider to relocate it.